# How can I check if a specific file exists on a given path?

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I want to implement a functionality to display the user's avatar. When a user uploads his image it will be automatically saved on the server with his username.

When I display the image source will be based on a path /images/users/avatars/username

```
% if ($self->session('role') eq 'Admin') {
  <div class="picture-container">
  % my $path = Mojo::File->new("/images/users/avatars/$username");
  <%= l($path) %>
    % if (defined $path) {
         <img src="/images/users/avatars/<%= $username %>"
    % } else {
         <img src="/images/users/avatars/default.png"
    % }
              class="img-thumbnail"
              alt="Responsive image" id="picture">
  </div>
```

% }

But if the file doesn't exist I want to display a default avatar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
my $path_string = $path->path;   # get path from Mojo::File object
if (-e $path_string)
```

...will check if the file exists. [perldoc -f -X](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X)

Comment: didn't work, the path might not be defined properly?

Comment: I see now that `$path` is a `Mojo::File` object, I just assumed it was a path. You should probably be able to get the path from `$path->path`. Perl will want a *nix style path. e.g. `images/foo` or `/home/user/www/images/foo`.